# Window manual minimize override my WindowState setter in DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, window, fullscreen, datatrigger

So I've got DataTrigger binded to TriggerButton IsChecked property in my ResourceDictionary.

After button is pressed, window goes full screen.

The problem is, when i manually minimalize window, WindowState is set in code by WPF to minimize and it override my DataTrigger setter, so i can't go full screen again. Is there any way to prevent WPF from override, while leaving functionality of window minimialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a property in the code behind instead that updates the WindowState based on a bool property of the checkbox.

Example:

```
public WindowState MainWindowState 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return (IsChecked) ? WindowState.Maximized : WindowState.Normal;
    }
}

private bool _isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get
    {
        return _isChecked;
    }
    set
    {
        _isChecked = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        OnPropertyCHanged("MainWindowState");
    }
}
```

This is not a great MVVM approach but it should accomplish what you're trying to do.